# React-Native, unable to align button at bottom in iPhone X

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am applying some style for button. Motive is button should align at parent bottom and have some margin or padding from bottom .

**So I applied below style**

```
bottomView: {
  width: '85%',
  height: 50,
  marginLeft: 10,
  marginRight: 10,
  borderRadius: 5,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  backgroundColor: ColorConstants.COLOR_BUTTON,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'center',
  position: 'absolute',
  bottom: 25
}
```

**I have checked on Android devices, iPhone simulators it was working fine. But this is not working on iPhone X simulator.**

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You Have to mention that, it is in `SafeAreaView`:

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}}>
// Your Code//
</SafeAreaView>
```